# What does gpt7 refers to in my grub.cfg

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

Here is the content of this file `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu`:

```
search.fs_uuid 379c9bee-90c4-4224-a821-e881268277fe root hd0,gpt7 
set prefix=($root)'/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

I would like to add another boot partition before this boot partition. Is that "gpt7" a counter for the numbering of the partition? It seems to indeed be the 7th partition on that disk, but I want to be sure.

So, should I change "gpt7" to "gpt8" in that config file? Or should I rather run the grub config tool once after having created the new partition within GParted while still logged in my Ubuntu?

Any suggestions on how should I proceed? I am setting up a triple-boot on my dual-boot system. I need to have the "/boot" part on my first disk, since the second disk is not recognized by the motherboard directly at startup for booting due to it being added after on a laptop with an SSD caddy. So my "/" is in my 2nd disk, despite the "/boot/efi" is elsewhere on the 1st disk, too.

Comment: gpt7 refers to your (root) partition. GPT - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://www.anchor.com.au/blog/2012/10/the-difference-between-booting-mbr-and-gpt-with-grub/ . What are you wanting to know exactly ?

Comment: the UUID & drive,partition are the / or /boot, if separate partition, where the full grub.cfg is located. I back up /EFI/ubuntu. A new install will overwrite that grub.cfg. All Ubuntu based systems using Ubuntu's grub2 install grub to /EFI/ubuntu and mount in fstab at /boot/efi. And now inside your install permissions are restricted on that mount, probably for security reasons. Old mount used defaults and could be edited from inside your install. https://askubuntu.com/questions/738132/ubuntu-14-04-doesnt-boot-grub-prompt

Comment: Shouldn't it be "sda7" instead of "gpt7"? Is it safe to assume it is roughly the same thing?

Comment: And sure, I would back up all the content of /EFI which I got used to edit, and which also contains REFInd

Comment: Thanks @oldfred, it says that in their case `hd0,gpt2` equates to `/dev/sda2`. And knowing which .cfg file of the existing two is updated with `sudo update-grub` is useful to know. Still, it think it's strange to name the sda7 as gpt7...

Comment: When grub loads, you have not mounted any drives or partitions, so the standard sda7 does not apply. Grub used to use (hd0,1) for first drive first partition. But now with MBR(msdos) or gpt(GUID) it also includes which type of partitioning is used. Once Ubuntu mounts partition then it will be sda1.