# Triple boot to dual boot: how do I uninstall Lubuntu without screwing up GRUB?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, lubuntu

I'm triple booting at the moment with Linux Mint, Lubuntu, and Windows 10. I'm trying to remove Lubuntu, but it screws up GRUB every time I do.

Here's what I'm doing:

1. List item
2. Remove the Lubuntu partition via GParted
3. run "sudo update-grub"
4. Reboot computer
5. GRUB menu no longer shows up, GRUB is now just a command line.
6. Reinstall Lubuntu to make GRUB menu come back because I couldn't find any other way
7. Repeat

I'm wondering if there's something I can do to bring GRUB back but without having to reinstall Lubuntu. Boot-Repair hasn't solved the problem and I'm all out of ideas.

Thanks for answering my question, in advance!

EDIT: I am using a UEFI system.

EDIT 2: I fixed my problem! I should have thought to run Boot-repair from my Mint partition instead of from a live CD. No wonder Boot-repair didn't work! Silly me. My problem has been solved!

Comment: Boot-Repair should work. But post link to summary report from it, if it does not work.  UEFI or BIOS system? You want to first change boot loader to system you are keeping and make sure it works, before deleting Lubuntu partition.

Comment: If UEFI, you should be able to set boot order with efibootmgr. Also in UEFI itself, you can set boot order, or when booting, go into UEFI's boot menu and select to boot any installed system. With multiple versions of Ubuntu though you will only have one /EFI/ubuntu folder and have to edit grub.cfg or reinstall grub. http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr grub.cfg in /EFI/ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/738132/ubuntu-14-04-doesnt-boot-grub-prompt & https://askubuntu.com/questions/957914/dual-boot-14-04-17-04-lost-grub-menu/958220#958220

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the exact answer to your problem, but when I had similar problems with grub, I got help by [this guide](https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd). Especially the part about the mounting was important.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. Please edit your answer and copy the parts that you find important from the site you linked, so it'll still be available if the link becomes dead. And keep the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have Windows boot manager + grub boot manager installed on your Lubuntu partition. That's why after removing the Lubuntu partition, you no longer can boot.

Try installing grub on the Linux Mint partition, and update the bootloader to load it instead of the one on Lubuntu. Once you get that working, you can safely remove your Lubuntu parition.

Answer (score 0):

Install Boot-Repair in Linux Mint. Run Boot-repair from your Linux Mint partition instead of running it from a live CD/USB, so that Boot-Repair will recognize the grub that is installed in Linux Mint. Then you can delete the Lubuntu partition and run `sudo update-grub` from Linux Mint in order to update grub which will remove the unusable Lubuntu entry from the GRUB boot menu.