# On Dual boot (Grub default) Win10- Ubuntu18.4 system I want to install Peppermint 9

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

On a Dual boot (Grub default) Win10- Ubuntu18.4 system on a  Dell Inspiron 15 3567

I want to install Peppermint9 as a 3rd system- will it figure out how to add itself to the Ubuntu GRUB, overwrite GRUB with it's own and all 3 systems, destroy it so nothing boots, or how do I do that myself?

Comment: Do not know Peppermint. Some use /EFI/ubuntu even if not Ubuntu. It really should use /EFI/peppermint as UEFI folder. If it uses /EFI/ubuntu you need to backup ESP. But real issue is the entry in /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg.

Comment: Thanks Fred: Peppermint is essentially blazingly fast light LXDE netbook version of Ubuntu 18, uses same repositories. Peppermintos.com  Backup Extra Sensory Perception? Thanks- will ask the Peppermint boys, maybe have to waylay Grub installation and manually edit Ubuntu GRUB, or just make it search for systems again.

Comment: I have multiple installs of Ubuntu and now just edit the /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg back to main working install's UUID & partition . Example here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/738132/ubuntu-14-04-doesnt-boot-grub-prompt & https://askubuntu.com/questions/957914/dual-boot-14-04-17-04-lost-grub-menu/958220#958220

Answer (score 0):

You should just add the third partition like you did with the second os.
This guide should apply. Just replace Mint with Peppermint!

> Just install normally. You can boot from your USB and follow the steps of the installer. You can either create a partition manually
>   before installing or use the tools provided by the Mint installer to
>   partition during the installation process.
>
> The only thing you really have to worry about is when the installer
>   asks you whether to install a boot loader (GRUB). Then, you have 2
>   choices. Since you already have a GRUB installed by Ubuntu, you can
>   either choose to not install a new one from mint and use Ubuntu's or
>   you can install Mint's and overwrite Ubuntu's.
>
> Use the existing GRUB.
>
> When the installer asks you whether to install a boot loader, say no.
>   Once the installation has finished, reboot and load Ubuntu (Mint will
>   not appear in the list of available OSs). From Ubuntu, refresh GRUB so
>   it will detect your new Mint installation:
>
> sudo update-grub
>
> Use Mint's GRUB.
>
> When the installer asks you whether to install a boot loader, say yes.
>   Make sure you install it in the same location where your Ubuntu's GRUB
>   was installed. This will probably be the master boot record (MBR) of
>   your primary hard drive. Reboot and you should now have Mint's GRUB
>   installed and will be able to choose Mint, Ubuntu or Windows.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155406

Comment: Thanks Dudeamax. That seems pretty painless.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu found the aborted Pep installation (bad disk) on an update and added it, but Peppermint overwrote it with it's own more primitive bootloader, which found all OS's.